# Laravel Routing Group - use value in Controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

All my requests are starting with a prefix, so I created a Route Group with multiple endpoints:

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => $prefix), function() { 
    Route::get("/test/test2/{lang}", ['uses' => 'TestController@test2']);
    ...
});
```

**Controller:**

```
class TestController {
  public function test2(Request $request, $lang) {}
}
```

With the following test URL:

```
domain.com/customprefix/test/test2/en
```

I reach my controller and can access `$lang` (=en). But how can I pass `$prefix` to my controller methods? (It should evaluate to "customprefix" in this example)

Unfortunately I didn't find information about that in the documentation or in the API specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Controller` you can get prefixes as one of these solutions:

1.With `$reques`:

```
 public function TestController(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
  $request->route()->getPrefix();
}
```

2.Without `$request`:

```
$this->getRouter()->getCurrentRoute()->getPrefix()
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use route prefix already ? . If not, so it should look like this

```
public function test2(Request $request, $lang){
   dd($request->route()->getPrefix());
}
```